# What versions of Windows CE and Windows Mobile support WebSockets in their browsers?

Tags: html, mobile, websocket, windows-ce

I'm looking at re-writing an enterprise class native C++ terminal emulation application that (currently) uses Curses/Ncurses.  We would like to go from that, all the way to an HTML5/WebSocket solution.  (Seems fun, right?)

Previously, the legacy terminal emulation application was reached (by clients) using telnet.  The server, of course, executed the Curses application; but this TEXT-based Curses technology is very old; new hardware these days is probably powerful enough to run the client application natively, or run an HTML5/WebSocket web application?

Windows CE and Windows Mobile are near end-of-life and the future of these operating systems and their hardware vendors seems fickle at best? Everything could "go Android" for example, over the course of the next 5 years.

I would like to replace this legacy C++ terminal emulation application with a full blown HTML5/WebSocket application that communicates with a back end application server.

Caveat:  I need to know (early on) if such an HTML5/WebSocket solution will force existing customers to migrate onto new hardware (in order to have a web browser that supports the WebSocket protocol) or if they can "re-purpose" existing equipment that currently has a Windows CE 5/6.5, Windows Mobile 5/6.5/7, or Windows Embedded operating system.

Caveat 2: Also, it seems that even the latest and greatest RF devices (Radio Frequency guns) are still running Windows Mobile 6.5 or Windows CE 6?

I have not been able to discover (at Microsoft, IE Dev Center, et. al.) a table that lists operating systems and browsers capable of HTML5 and/or just WebSocket protocol.

Comment: I have stumbled upon ZetaKey which kind of promises that it brings HTML5 (bullet list contains WebSocket!) to Windows Mobile 6.1.  Hmmmm... http://www.zetakey.com/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lowest target is IE10 / IE10 Mobile according to [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/websockets).

Your best bet would be to use [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client) or implement native sockets in the app yourself and proxy it to the browser widget. 
*(might be using the wrong terms, I don't use any kind of windows nor do any kind of windows programming)*

Comment: Yes, I saw that IE10 is the lowest common denominator there at can-i-use earlier, but Windows CE/Mobile have "special" browsers, like "Internet Explorer for Windows CE" for example.  (But what version of IE is that, and if it is IE10, is it the IE10 Mobile, and does that support WebSockets?

Comment: IE10 Mobile is only available on Windows 8 phones.

Comment: Okay, I'm beginning to think this ZetaKey kind of solution would be the best bet.  It is "a Webkit-based browser solution that offers HTML5 compliance, high-performance browser for Embedded Linux, Windows CE 5/6, Compact 7 and Windows Mobile."

Comment: Just make sure it supports websockets before you spend a lot of time working on it, until recently chrome and the default android browsers didn't support websockets.

Comment: Yes, one of the HTML5 features right on the Zeta landing page lists WebSocket in the bullet list.  That really has my attention--granted testing would need to be done to confirm that such a "webkit-based" browser is going to be viable (performance, latency) on 2-yr-old equipment running Windows Mobile 6.1 (for example.)

Comment: IMHO, I'd say a native socket implementation and using the default browser (I'm almost sure you can extend it), would be much better performance-wise, WebSockets protocol is rather easy to implement.